# Laplace transform of f'', L(f'')

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I'm looking for the Laplace Transform solution to the following problem, [image]

Here is my attempt at a solution, however I am confused about the integration of *f(t)*

$\mathscr{L}${*f''*} = $\int_0^\infty$*f''*(*t*)*e*$^{-st}$*dt* = $s^{2}$F(*s*) - $sf(0) - f'(0)$

$\hspace{10mm} u = e^{-st} \hspace{19mm} dv = f''(t)$

$\hspace{10mm} du = -se^{-st} \hspace{11mm} v=f'(t)$

$e^{-st} * f'(t) - s*\int f'(t)e^{-st} dt$

$\hspace{10mm} u = u^{-st} \hspace{19mm} dv = f'(t)$

$\hspace{10mm}du = -se^{-st} \hspace{12mm} v = f(t)$

$f'(t)e^{-st} + s[e^{-st}f(t) + s\int f(t)-se^{-st} dt]$

$f'(t) e^{-st} + se ^{-st} +s^2 * \int f(t)e^{-st} dt$

evaluated from $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: Is the problem that you don't understand IBP? what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, thank you all. i will post my work later tonight. I meant to earlier but was having difficulties using mathjax. (i’m a physics major and as of yet know minimal cs) sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

hint:
$$u=e^{-st},v'=f''$$
then repeat